# I want to delete user from perforce group through my python script

Tags: python, perforce, p4python

This command i got from perforce manual:

```
p4 group -o group_name | grep -v user_name | p4 group -i
```

How can i use this command in my script using method p4.run()

Answer (score 1):

There's an example in the P4Python docs of how to update a spec:

https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r14.2/manuals/p4script/python.p4.html#python.p4.save_spectype

From looking at other examples it sounds like a multi-line field (e.g. the Users field in the group spec) is represented in the spec dict as a list.  So I think what you want is something like:

```
from P4 import P4, P4Exception
p4 = P4()

try:
  p4.connect()
  group = p4.fetch_group( "group_name" )
  group[ "Users" ].remove( "user_name" )
  p4.save_group( group )

except P4Exception:
  for e in p4.errors:
    print e

finally:
  p4.disconnect()
```